# Can't push to the branch with ssh. ERROR: You are not allowed to push code to this project

Tags: git

I have the ssh-key, that I use for one git repository.
Now I have created my own repository (gitlab) and added a new ssh-rsa key for this repository.
The reason why I created a new ssh key - I received error when I tried to add a my existing `id_rsa`.
So, I created a new `id_rsa_2.pub` and added this key to the my new git repo.

- proof:

[image: 1]

After that I have created a new project, copied a ssh path and now I try to use my git repo:

```
git init
git remote add origin git@gitlab.{username}/{repo}.git
git add .
```

Also I have updated a global info:

```
 git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
 git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Now, when I try to push, I received `ERROR: You are not allowed to push code to this project.`

## How to resolve this issue?

---

additional info: All my access options have status `Everyone with access`

Comment: `But I do not want to use username/password and https connection` Git still needs your name and email address, this has nothing to do with authentication.

Comment: SSH just allows you a way to connect to the remote server. But you still need to tell the server who you are so it can determine what capabilities you have. Whether you have permissions to access the repo, whether or not you can push changes to a branch, etc.

Comment: @tkausl, Thank you. The first issue I have resolved :)
But the main issue - is still actual